# record audio with builtin and external mic simultaneously

Tags: macos, microphone, audio-recording, matlab

I want to record two channels of audio into Matlab on OSX, using the internal microphone and an external usb microphone at the same time.

Is this possible without any additional hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how you would do that directly from Matlab, but what I'd do is record audio using two different programs (e.g. Quicktime and Garageband or some other freeware to record audio) and choose two different sources in the settings for each application. After recording, you can import the files into Matlab.

You'll also have to find a way to start recording simultaneously, for which I'd record an Automator script or use Applescript.